# cannot join to master node using kubeadm join

Tags: centos, kubernetes

I am trying to set up a kubernetes cluster and running this command on my worker node
`kubeadm join server:port --token xxx  --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:xxxx`
and the error i have is

```
Found multiple CRI endpoints on the host. Please define which one do you wish to use by setting the 'criSocket' field in the kubeadm configuration file: unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock, unix:///var/run/cri-dockerd.sock
```

I am not sure which container runtime to use here, so i modified the command as
`kubeadm join server:port --token xxx  --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:xxxx --cri-socket /var/run/crio/crio.sock`
but the error is

```
[ERROR CRI]: container runtime is not running: output: I0617 21:55:27.908044 1877581 util_unix.go:103] "Using this endpoint is deprecated, please consider using full URL format" endpoint="/var/run/crio/crio.sock" URL="unix:///var/run/crio/crio.sock"
E0617 21:55:27.908867 1877581 remote_runtime.go:616] "Status from runtime service failed" err="rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while dialing dial unix /var/run/crio/crio.sock: connect: no such file or directory\""
time="2023-06-17T21:55:27+05:30" level=fatal msg="getting status of runtime: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while dialing dial unix /var/run/crio/crio.sock: connect: no such file or directory\""
, error: exit status 1
```

Can someone suggest the correct approach here

Answer (score 0):

https://technokofe.com/2022/08/22/kubernetes-upgrade-v1-23-to-v1-24-common-errors-and-solutions/

Maybe the above link will help you.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note that [link-only answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) are discouraged, as the link may become invalid or the linked content change. Please 
edit your answer to include at least a summary of the linked explanation.